# Run testthat tests on only one GitHub actions job

Tags: r, github-actions, testthat

Some tests for a [package](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR) require repeatedly deleting and writing data on a single test server.  I can't run those tests simultaneously, because they'd interfere with each other.

Three goals:

1. I'd like to run a GitHub Action job on three different OSes (Ubuntu, macOS, & Windows).
2. I'd like to run the delete+write tests only on the Ubuntu job on GitHub  --I want to skip them for mac & Windows only if it's run on GitHub actions.
3. But I don't want them skipped when run on someone's local mac or Windows machine (and [Win-Builder](https://win-builder.r-project.org/)).  Theoretically two developers could step on each other's toes, but it happens too infrequently to care.

A few notes:

- Ideally a version of the target server is temporarily spun up & hosted within GitHub actions.  However I'm not sure that's allowed with the [REDCap](https://www.project-redcap.org/) license.
- About 20% of the ~200 testthat checks should be skipped.  The rest either don't call the server, or are readonly operations.  So it doesn't matter if two jobs/OSes run them simultaneously.
- On all jobs, all non-testthat parts of the R-CMD check should run (*eg*, checking package dependencies & vignettes).

Is there a way to combine [testthat skips](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/vignettes/skipping.html) with [GitHub Action environmental variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables)?  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Does [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif) help accomplish what you want? For example, if you set up a matrix OS build for macOS, Ubuntu, and Windows, and had a step for your test setup, execution, and teardown, you could add an `if` directive to that step to only run if the OS starts with 'ubuntu': `if: startsWith(${{matrix.os}}, 'ubuntu')`.